# How to statistically compare the performance of machine learning regression algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test

Let say that I want to compare the performance of XGBoost vs NN, or NN vs NN, or even the same NN at different epochs for a regression task.

All algorithms are trained and evaluated on the exact same dataset.

My thought is to compare the distribution of the residuals i.e.: set up a hypothesis test such tha $\mu_{xgb} > \mu_{nn}$, or do a t-test,...

Here is an example I was working on ...

[image]

[image]

As you may see, both models are similar, both are non-normally distributed, but NN's have a larger variance. I did not know how to compare, so I selected a paired Wilcoxon Signed-rank test since it does not assume a normal distribution. As expected, p-value was really low that the median of XGBoost is less than the median of NN.

I have no idea if this is kosher - but I could not find anything online.

Also, I was very surprised of how biased both models are in regions with the most frequent data. In terms of linear regression models - both of them would be considered terrible models. I would think QQ-plots would be a better measure than i.e.: feature importance in the case of XGBoost, if we assume

$$y = f(x, w) + \epsilon$$

where $x$ is the input and $w$ are weights in both models.

Comment: Doing something like an ANOVA sounds fine if the task is regression.  If the task is classification, something like a chi-square sounds good to me.

Comment: The objectives of the analysis are a key input to determining how to compare different methods.  (That's one reason there are so many possibilities of comparison.)